# Hierarchical order inside the <head>?

Tags: javascript, html

I've been creating sites with HTML etc. since almost 3 years, but as i had to learn it on my own, i still don't know a few things exactely.

One fundamental question has now become quite important: Can i create groups inside the  elements? Just like this:

```
<head>
  <meta ... />
  <group name='global_stylesheets'>
    <link href='...' />
    <link href='...' />
  </group>
  <group>
    ...
  </group>
</head>
```

If it's not possible in normal HTML, can i somehow add these group tags with javascript? And can I disable 'old' stylesheets and load new ones in javascript like this:

```
somelinks = '<link href='...' />\n<link href='...' />';
document.getElementsByTagName('groups')[2].innerHTML = someLinks;
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this? Depending one that someone could probably give you feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, HTML doesn't provide a way to structurally arrange the elements in the `<head>` section into groups, but you can use the `class` attribute to put them into logical groups:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" class="bigtext" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" class="bigtext" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style3.css" class="smalltext" />       
    ...
</head>
```

Then you can do something like this to disable the ones you don't need (I'm using jQuery for brevity, but you can do the same without jQuery):

```
$(".bigtext").each(function() {
    this.disabled = true;
});
```

If for some reason you want to use JavaScript to add new stylesheets to your page, you can just create the `<link>` elements and add them to the page's `head`:

```
function addStylesheet(href) {
    var sty = document.createElement("link");
    sty.rel = "stylesheet";
    sty.href = href;
    document.head.appendChild(sty);
}

addStylesheet("style3.css");
addStylesheet("style4.css");
```

And here's the jQuery version of that:

```
function addStylesheet(href) {
    $(document.head).append($("<link rel='stylesheet'>").attr("href", href));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your entire approach is very wrong.

You should reconsider how your stylesheets are build up. The whole point of stylesheets are that they are supposed to be global across the page. You should instead limit what they style with classes and ids.

Again, there's no point in grouping stylesheets like you are doing.

Comment: This does not answer the question; should have been posted as a comment if at all.